# Carete and run activity in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I read it's documents but I didn't find anything about create or launch activity there!
How can I create new activity and launch it or manage it's special behaviors like onPause() and etc...?
In fact there is just a file as "index.android.js". I guess I can create new files like this for new activity(!) but I don't know how to manage them!

Comment: You went through documentation and tutorial? Good then what you need now is this: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux lots of examples how to create an app with navigation and multiple scenes

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. Using React Navigation  I can hold this job!
https://reactnavigation.org/